# How the wire of an electric motor produce electricity

Tags: solenoid

If the wire of a electric motor is insulated, then how will it produce electricity? ??

Answer (score 1):

What "makes" electricity is a variation of magnetic flux. The wire is just a support for the electricity. It could as well be a ionized gas or liquid...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHD_generator

```
Michael Faraday first proposed the idea in his "Bakerian lecture for 1832" to the Royal 
Society. He carried out experiments at Waterloo Bridge, measuring current from the flow
of the Thames in the Earth's magnetic field.
```

Answer (score 0):

The ends of the wire aren't insulated, they're connected to brushes usually. The brushes connect up with the rest of the circuit, either a load or a battery usually. Different kinds of electric motors make this connection in different ways. Note that some electric motors may not be used as generators (electricity producing machines).